# Weird behavior on recycler view and coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I have used RecyclerView in CoordinatorLayout like this

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/txtLayoutInvestment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/investmentAmount"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/inputProjectInvestmentHint"
                android:inputType="number"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/loanList"
                    android:textSize="20sp"/>

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/btAddLoan"
                    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="end"
                    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/loanList"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scrollbars="vertical">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btBack"
                style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="@string/back_button"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btCancel"
                style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="@string/cancel_button"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btNext"
                style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:text="@string/next_button"
                android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Everything works fine until I input something on above editText and touch next on keyboard

[image: Input on editext and touch next on keyboard]

[image: Weird display]

I guess it caused by configuration for coordinator layout or recyclerview behavior but I have not idea to fix it. Please help

*170418 UPDATE: If going back app after pressing home button, then the display is normal.

Comment: add maxlines="1" and inputtype=text in textinputEdittext

Comment: Please share error logs .

Comment: Here it is 04-15 17:58:16.617 8716-8716/com.novakduc.forbega.qlnt E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Comment: It is not because of this error. I have solved this error but display still same.

Comment: It is advisable to change recyclerview height to wrap_content.Also be sure to attach LayoutManager to the recyclerview.

Comment: @SriMaharshiManchem thank you so much! It's been solved by your advice. If it is possible, please teach me how to find out the reason. I mean why it happens like that.

Comment: @NovakDuc I'm happy that the comment is useful for you.I have worked on the similar scenario. Recycler view in layout with weight.Please flag the above comment as useful.

Comment: @SriMaharshiManchem Sorry! It is weird. But I am new. Where can I flag a comment? Please show me. Thank you so much!

Comment: you can find uparrow image  to the left of comment. hover over white space ,it will be visible . If you couldn't find it no problem.